# I want to convert tbl_df to ts for time series analysis. I have done it but lost my (Month) column which is date in my data

Tags: r, time-series, rstudio, gis

I am trying to convert my data set **tbl_df** into time series **(ts)** to perform the forecasting ARIMA model. 
These are the first 5 rows of my original dataset;

```
   Month      count
   <date>     <int>
 1 2016-01-01   431
 2 2016-02-01   478
 3 2016-03-01   468
 4 2016-04-01   488
 5 2016-05-01   445
```

After a successful conversion I have lost the Month column and got a strange date.
I have used the following code for conversion into ts;

```
 crime_monthly1 <- as.ts(crime_monthly)
```

I got this with Month col changes into strange numbers;

```
   Month count
 1 16801   431
 2 16832   478
 3 16861   468
 4 16892   488
 5 16922   445
```

I have applied this code to convert the date and whole dataset into ts but could not helped;

```
crime_monthly1$Month <- as.Date(crime_monthly1$Month, format = "%m/%d/%Y")
ts(crime_monthly1[,-1], start = as.Date(crime_monthly1$Month[1]), frequency = 1)
```

I got the following error;

```
Error in crime_monthly1$Month : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

The other issue is that I am getting ***Frequency just 1***. Though my dataset is having monthly temporal resolution with 36 months, which i think should be 12 as in 1 year there are 12 months.

Can anyone please tell me the complete procedure for doing this. I am really sorry but I new to R and I searched previous questions also but could not found the exact solution in my case.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest approach is this.

```
crime_ts <- ts(crime_monthly$count, start=2016, frequency=12)
```

But you might find it better to use a `tsibble` object rather than a `ts` object.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(tsibble)

crime_monthly <- tribble(
    ~Month,      ~count,
    "2016-01-01",  431,
    "2016-02-01",  478,
    "2016-03-01",  468,
    "2016-04-01",  488,
    "2016-05-01",  445) %>%
  mutate(Month = as.Date(Month))

crime_tsibble <- as_tsibble(crime_monthly, index=Month) %>%
  mutate(
    Month = yearmonth(Month)
  )
crime_tsibble
#> # A tsibble: 5 x 2 [1M]
#>      Month count
#>      <mth> <dbl>
#> 1 2016 Jan   431
#> 2 2016 Feb   478
#> 3 2016 Mar   468
#> 4 2016 Apr   488
#> 5 2016 May   445
```

<sup>Created on 2020-02-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Tools for using tsibble objects are in the `tsibble`, `feasts` and `fable` packages.

Comment: Thank you so much dear Mr. Rob. It totally worked for me the way you showed. Bundles of thanks

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the input shown reproducibly in the Note at the end, convert it to a zoo object `z` using the `yearmon` index class which represents year/months. Then `as.ts` will convert it to `ts` class with the correct frequency.

```
library(zoo)

z <- read.zoo(DF, FUN = as.yearmon)
tt <- as.ts(z)

tt
##      Jan Feb Mar Apr May
## 2016 431 478 468 488 445

frequency(tt)
## [1] 12

class(tt)
## [1] "ts"
```

### Note

The input in reproducible form is assumed to be:

```
Lines <- "   Month      count
 1 2016-01-01   431
 2 2016-02-01   478
 3 2016-03-01   468
 4 2016-04-01   488
 5 2016-05-01   445"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines)
```